# Doctrine Multiple Join Query gives an error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I m writing a query in Doctrine 2.3.3, where i want to retrieve data from 4 different tables. Now i have written a query which works on single join. But when i write multiple join queries it shows an error..

My query is

```
$query = $parent->entityManager->createQuery('SELECT t,s,q,d FROM TblEmployee t JOIN TblEmployeeShifts s JOIN TblEmployeeQualification q JOIN TblEmployeeDepartment d where t.employeeId = s.employeeId and t.employeeId = d.employeeId and t.employeeId = q.employeeId and t.employeeId ='.$data);
```

but the above query gives me an error, shown below,

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 89: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'q'
```

Pls guide me where i m stepping wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the ways using which we can execute Mulitple Joins in Doctrine

```
$query = $parent->entityManager->createQuery('
    SELECT t,s,d,q 
    FROM TblEmployee t
    JOIN TblEmployeeDepartment s WITH t.employeeId = s.employeeId
    JOIN TblEmployeeShifts d WITH t.employeeId = d.employeeId
    JOIN TblEmployeeQualification q WITH t.employeeId = q.employeeId 
         and t.employeeId = '.$data
);
```